# Why fetch cursor slow in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor

I have a big table with about 100 millions rows per month.
When I create cursor for  this month's records:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM marketo.activities
WHERE activitydate>'2019-07-01'::timestamp;
FETCH 1 FROM cur;
```

It works very slow. I waited 5 minutes and cancel it. I have index on activitydate column.
Why it is so, isn't cursor supposed to work fast fetching just one row from big query?